# Transición fade al cargar la página

Tags: javascript, html, transicion

estoy intentando hacer una transición `fadeIn()` con la carga de mi página en un elemento en concreto pero no lo estoy consiguiendo.

Este es el último script que he puesto y que tampoco ha funcionado:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).load(function () {
        $("#info").fadeIn();
    });
</script>
```

Y este es el código HTML donde tengo el párrafo que quiero que se cargue con la página:

```
<article>
   <p id="info">
       TEXTO PRUEBA
   </p>
</article>
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: No sería usar ‘.ready()’ en lugar de ‘.load()’ para que se ejecute cuando ya ha cargado la página?

Comment: Lo he cambiado y no me ha funcionado tampoco.

Comment: Chequea esta web http://stringmanolo.ml/dhunter/ trasteo bastante con eso de esconder elementos, esperar a que se cargen, mostrar y ocultar, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira, te pasan dos cosas. Por un lado estas usando `load()` cuando la función que tendrías que usar es `ready`, aunque de todas formas seguirás viendo que el `FadeIn` no se realiza. En realidad lo hace, pero el texto aparece demasiado rápido. 
Acá te dejo un código que ademas de mostrar texto, aplica un color de fondo, de esa manera se puede apreciar correctamente el funcionamiento.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#info").fadeIn();
});
</script>

<article>
   <p id="info" style="width:100%;display:none;background-color:red;">
       TEXTO PRUEBA
   </p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente me faltaba cambiar, como bien habéis dicho, el `load()` por el `ready()` y añadir a la hoja de estilos el `display: none` que había quitado en algún momento.
Para darle más elegancia puse lo siguiente:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#info").fadeIn(1000);
    });
</script>
```

Así tarda un segundo en completar la transición y queda mejor.
Muchas gracias a los dos!